# ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs) in lstm NN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I have this code(it was written with chatgpt):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message="The default value of regex will change from True to False")

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

df['Дата'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Дата'], format='%d.%m.%Y')

df['Откр.'] = df['Откр.'].str.replace('.', '').astype(str)
df['Откр.'] = df['Откр.'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
df['Закр.'] = df['Закр.'].str.replace('.', '').astype(str)
df['Закр.'] = df['Закр.'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
df['Макс.'] = df['Макс.'].str.replace('.', '').astype(str)
df['Макс.'] = df['Макс.'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
df['Мин.'] = df['Мин.'].str.replace('.', '').astype(str)
df['Мин.'] = df['Мин.'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
df['Объём'] = df['Объём'].str.replace('B', '0000000').str.replace(',', '').astype(str)
df['Объём'] = df['Объём'].str.replace('M', '0000').str.replace(',', '').astype(str)
df['Объём'] = df['Объём'].str.replace('K', '0').str.replace(',', '').astype(str)
df['Объём'] = df['Объём'].astype(float)
df['Изм. %'] = df['Изм. %'].str.replace('%', '').str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)

X = df[['Откр.', 'Макс.', 'Мин.', 'Объём', 'Изм. %']]
Y = df['Закр.']

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, Y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)

def prepare_data(data, look_back=1):
    X, Y = [], []
    for i in range(len(data)-look_back):
        X.append(data[i:(i+look_back)])
        Y.append(data[i+look_back])
    return np.array(X), np.array(Y)

look_back = 1097 
X_train, Y_train = prepare_data(Y_train.values.reshape(-1,1), look_back)
X_test, Y_test = prepare_data(Y_test.values.reshape(-1,1), look_back)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(look_back, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=16, verbose=2)

test_predict = model.predict(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], look_back, X_test.shape[1]))
test_predict = model.predict(X_test)
Y_test = scaler.inverse_transform(Y_test.reshape(-1, 1))

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mse = mean_squared_error(Y_test, test_predict)
print('MSE:', mse)
```

Don't pay attention to Russian. The neural network should take data from the csv file and "Predict" the price.
csv file look like this:

> "Дата","Закр.","Откр.","Макс.","Мин.","Объём","Изм. %"
> "01.01.2023","1.200,52","1.195,69","1.204,12","1.191,67","126,62K","0,41%"
> "31.12.2022","1.195,67","1.200,00","1.207,71","1.193,16","150,20K","-0,34%"
> "30.12.2022","1.199,80","1.200,84","1.202,13","1.186,10","285,77K","-0,09%"
> "29.12.2022","1.200,84","1.189,99","1.205,34","1.187,19","272,59K","0,91%"
> "28.12.2022","1.189,98","1.211,60","1.214,32","1.184,22","407,45K","-1,78%"
> "27.12.2022","1.211,60","1.228,22","1.233,15","1.202,02","290,02K","-1,31%"
> "26.12.2022","1.227,65","1.218,69","1.230,37","1.213,08","177,66K","0,73%"
> "25.12.2022","1.218,69","1.220,46","1.223,82","1.201,20","256,52K","-0,15%"

I have 1097 such lines, not counting the first one.
When I run the code, it throws this error in line 53:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
> File "d:\program files\visualstudio\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy_main*.py", line 45, in <module>
> cli.main()
> File "d:\program files\visualstudio\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
> run()
> File "d:\program files\visualstudio\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
> runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("**main**"))
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 289, in run_path
> return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
>
> _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
> File "D:\VMS_Progect\SaleNN\SaleNN.py", line 53, in <module>
> model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=16, verbose=2)
> File "C:\Users\Alexey\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> File "C:\Users\Alexey\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1697, in fit
> raise ValueError(
> ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.

Before this code from 55 to 58 was:

```
test_predict = model.predict(X_test)
test_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predict)
Y_test = scaler.inverse_transform(Y_test.reshape(-1, 1))
```

and

```
look_back = 7
```

This error did not occur in this case. But there was a mistake:

> non-broadcastable output operand with shape (213,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (213,5)

I have tried this:
`model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=\['accuracy'\], run_eagerly=True)`

And this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

This was advised by chatgpt, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here I see many stupid things.

1. You had X_train with 5 columns. But then you applied this:

   X_train, Y_train = prepare_data(Y_train.values.reshape(-1,1), look_back)

   Which means you discarted all these 5 columns. Then why don't you just discard it at the beginning?
2. The MinMaxScaler here is fitted to your old X which are those 5 columns you discarded, so it becames completelly useless. You can't apply it.
3. **It's you problem of "Empty logs", I tried personally this code and I see that your look_back is too big**, which will make your X_train, Y_train empty. That is why your code gives you this error.